# NSLocalizedString() Swift just work with specified language

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

i want to use NSLocalizedString() for different languages.

Code in Swift-file:

```
NSLocalizedString("Hoechstgeschwindigkeit", comment: "Höchstgeschwindigkeit");
```

Code in .strings file

```
Hoechstgeschwindigkeit="Höchstgeschwindigkeit";
```

It works , when i change my system language to spanish and english.
It works also with german, but just when i edit the scheme and not when the system language is german and i don't know why.
When i use german as system language the app returns the default.strings content of the keys.

(the german Storyboard .string file works with system language)

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Now i know the problem...
For everyone having the same problem:
i checked out the language code in the .swift file with:

```
var preferredLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0] as String
```

it returns "de-DE" and not as expected "de"

yet, i don't know how to solve it, but i know the problem

Comment: Now i also know how to solve it... in the project settings you can choose other there you can search for languagecode-Country maybe for different dialects or something